# Best way to limit access to raw Joomla

Tags: component

I use several extensions and really only want users to access those extensions from within the menu item's I put them in. However it's clear that if you know the name of an extension you can see views of it and get around this.

```
index.php?option=com_component&view=view
```

How can I block this access to a component?

Cheers,

Mat

Comment: Just a similar request here with an example to block access to com_users in the front-end via htaccess: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14895/redirect-to-home-if-someone-tries-to-access-com-users-or-frontpage-editing-hta/14920#14920

Answer (score 2):

There are many extension available which can let you control the component accessibility.

You can check [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/) for this.

If you wish you have something which is minimalist and do the necessary then you can create your own plugin to handle this.

Joomla plugin creation is quite simple.
Below are some of the reference which you can refer for plugin development help.

[Plugin Development](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development)

[Joomla Events](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events)

[Creating  a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

All you need to do is fetch the option and view parameters on 
**onAfterRoute** trigger in your plugin and validated whether to pass this request or block.

Like below

```
public function onAfterRoute()
{
    $option =  JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option', '');
    $view   =  JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view', '');

   //Apply your logic here
}
```