# Redirect to home if someone tries to access com_users or frontpage editing (.htaccess, web.config)

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, redirect

I would like to redirect any trafic which tries to acces com_users (any view) or the frontpage editing `(index.php?option=com_content&view=form&layout=edit)` to the frontpage.

I don't want to use any extensions for this, so I'm looking for a solution with .htaccess and web.config

I'm not so familiar with rewrite conditions so I'm sure I doing it the wrong way. But couldn't figure out the right.

For example I tried this for web.config:

```
<rule name="Joomla! Rule 3, Deny com_users and editing">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/?option=com_users" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="layout=edit" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="index.php" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

end this for .htaccess:

```
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} com_users #added this to the original Joomla! code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} edit #added this to the original Joomla! code
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block access to certain url parameters/values like the **`option=com_users`** in the front end, you can try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=(com_users)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [F]
```

What the above does is:

1. Instructing to exclude the administrator site and it's required, otherwise you won't be able to access the com_users in admin site as well.
2. Checking for the query sting option=com_users in the url
3. Forbids access to it.

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly on Linux servers but I don't know why IIS ignores admin exclusion. Maybe I should use rewrite map instead of a simple rule. I will investigate it further. Oh and also I came up with a hack for the front end editing :) I added a simple code to my template which looks like this: `if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'edit' !== false){header("Location: http://mydomain.com/");}` and I'm also considering changing the file rights for edit to 444 so this way PHP can't execute the file :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont try Admin Exile plugin?
This plugin do exactly you need, and is free.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/adminexile

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will only protect access to administrator and restrict user groups on front end, but I already protect back end with OSE Security plug-in. Anyway Thanks for the answer.